# Bitcoin Core gives error "Error reading from database, shutting down" during first time setup

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have recently installed Bitcoin Core on my Gentoo system via portage. During the first time setup, the initial download stopped at roughly 30% completion and gave the error "Error reading from database, shutting down". Restarting the program would set the progress back a small amount and restart the download, but it would always fail at the same point. I tried running Bitcoin core with the -reindex flag, and after doing so the download made it farther - to 43.81% - but then gave the same error. As I mentioned before, this is during the first time download of the blockchain; I've never used the program for anything else.

Some points that may be important:

I have more than enough disk space.

I dualboot with Windows, and as such the first time I ran Bitcoin core I had a clock skew. It ran for a minute or so before I realized, closed the program and corrected it. I haven't run it with a clock skew since.

It almost always fails on the same point - in this case, at anywhere from 134577 to 134579 blocks remaining. After restarting, it starts the download at 134609, giving a difference of roughly 40 blocks. (As I mentioned before, however, it failed much earlier before reindexing.)

I installed through portage, and as such I have no reason to believe that any dependencies are missing.

Does this look like a hardware issue? I've yet to do any disk tests other than a simple ram test, which returned no issues. Thank you in advance.

EDIT

Here are some basic specifications for the machine in question.

CPU: Intel core i7 3930K, 6 core

GPU: Nvidia GTX 980 (open source drivers)

16GB of RAM, 8GB of swap

Kernel Version: 4.14.52-gentoo

Comment: How much RAM do you have on the machine that you're running this on.  Does increasing the swap space on the machine help?

Comment: 16GB of RAM, 8gb of swap. I haven't attempted to increase swap size.